# Alternative of deprecated methods/constants in Spotify IOS SDK beta 16

Tags: ios, spotify

I am using Spotify IOS SDK beta 6. I have to upgrade my SDK to beta 16. As I observed that many methods/constants of beta 6 version are mark deprecated version beta 16. SDK version beta 16 only marks them deprecated but not suggests any alternative of these methods. Please suggest from where I found these. Please find below few methods that mark deprecated:

- `(void)userInformationForUserInSession:(SPTSession *)session callback: SPTRequestCallback)block`
- `(void)albumWithURI:(NSURL *)uri session:(SPTSession *)session callback  (SPTRequestCallback)block`
- `SPTAudioStreamingMetadataTrackName (Constant)`
- `SPTAudioStreamingMetadataAlbumName (Constant)`
- `SPTAudioStreamingMetadataArtistURI (Constant)`
- `SPTAudioStreamingMetadataAlbumURI (Constant)`
- `SPTAudioStreamingMetadataTrackURI (Constant)`
- `SPTAudioStreamingMetadataArtistName (Constant)`
- `currentTrackMetadata (Its dictionary)`
- `(void)requestItemAtURI:(NSURL *)uri withSession:(SPTSession *)session callback:(SPTRequestCallback)block`
- `(void)performSearchWithQuery:(NSString *)searchQuery queryType (SPTSearchQueryType)searchQueryType session:(SPTSession *)session callback:(SPTRequestCallback)block`
- `(void)queueURI:(NSURL *)uri clearQueue:(BOOL)clear callback:(SPTErrorableOperationCallback)block`
- `(NSURL *)loginURLForClientId:(NSString *)clientId withRedirectURL:(NSURL *)redirectURL scopes:(NSArray *)scopes;`
- `(void)performSearchWithQuery:(NSString *)searchQuery queryType:(SPTSearchQueryType)searchQueryType session:(SPTSession *)session market:(NSString *)market callback:(SPTRequestCallback)block`
- `(void)requestItemFromPartialObject:(id <SPTPartialObject>)partialObject withSession:(SPTSession *)session callback:(SPTRequestCallback)block`